# JSP - printing a list wont work

Tags: java, html, list, jsp

**Update:** Everything works perfectly fine ... the OP was just being stupid - thanks to all the nice people looking for a flaw when there wasn't actually one - also thanks for suggestions

i need a little help with printing elements of a list - i have got some code but it wont display the elements from my list i created in the java part - thanks for any help in advance

Here is my html / .jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>  

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/user_management.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

        <table>
            <c:forEach items="${userList}" var="item">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${item}" /></td>
            </tr>
             </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is a part of my java code

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        list.add("User1");
        list.add("User2");

        request.setAttribute("userList", list);

        request.getRequestDispatcher("/user_management.jsp").include(request, response);

        return;
    }
```

Comment: What does it do instead?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I just woke up (still in bed though) ;-)

Comment: Unless it has some odd syntax error I can't see, it looks perfectly nice.  Are you sure that stylesheet (user_management.css) is not hiding any part of your page?  Have you tried to comment it?

Comment: Are you using Spring MVC? If so I would expect to see you adding this to the model not the attributes.

Comment: @JBNizet it prints just the usual html output and the <table></table> without anything inside

Comment: @Necator: click the edit link at the bottom of your question, and amend it with the generated HTML.

Comment: You're probably not executing the JSP you think you're executing. Try to add some static stuff inside and see if they appear. Also, any reason to use include instead of forward?

Comment: @TimB No, my setup for testing is XAMPP 3.2.1 and the java stuff with jstl-1.2 - sry im not an expert on this whole thing i just need to get this to work

Comment: The generated HTML doesn't match with the source code. You're probably not executing the JSP you think you're executing.

Comment: @JBNizet added generated html in my original post trying out the static stuff

Comment: @JBNizet oh wow..... it was the stupidest thing ever - i want to hit myself now - everything works perfectly fine if you actually use the Servlet ... if feel so dumb now (i always tried the .jsp instead of UserManagement) thanks for the effort and i am sorry to waste everyone's time because i am just being stupid

Comment: Time to buy a duck: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should access your USER_LIST variable something like ${requestScope.USER_LIST}

Use the lower camelCase naming convention

[Expression Language (Implicit objects)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html)

**Update**
I've just created the same setup as you mentioned in your question. I can access the variable USER_LIST and it also iterates over it. I also used an HttpServlet that sets the USER_LIST attribute in the request and then I iterate over this list in the JSP file. I could imagine that your setup is not complete. Check the web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SampleServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.m3ns1.sample.SampleServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SampleServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/users</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

I register the HttpServlet "SampleServlet" for the URL /users. The servlet then includes the user_management.jsp file. With this setup I can access the page under `http://localhost:8080/sample/users` which includes the user_management.jsp file under the project. Can you show us your configuration from your web.xml file?

Comment: There is no USER_LIST attribute in the page scope, so using requestScope is unnecessary. I agree about the naming convention, but that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: requestScope: Maps request-scoped variable names (USER_LIST) to their values -> ${requestScope.USER_LIST} should map your USER_LIST that you set in your HttpServlet (See "Expression Language" link)

Comment: Click the link you posted and read: *For example, when evaluating the expression ${product}, the container will look for product in the page, request, session, and application scopes and will return its value.* Since there is no USER_LIST in the page scope, the EL will find it in the request scope.

Comment: Ok i agree with that. Can you check if the ${USER_LIST} is found in your example, e.g. <c:out value="${USER_LIST}"/>. If the variable was found it should invoke its toString() method and therefore you should see the string representation of the USER_LIST at least

Comment: You should post this question as a comment to the question, or ad an `@Necator` to the comment if you want the OP to receive this question.